# Pyhton: list[i].append(x) adds x to list[i] and list[i+1]

Tags: python, list, append

I wrote this code in Python:

```
from random import choice as rc
cards = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11]
i = 0
player = [[9, 9]]
player[i] = [player[i][0]]
player.append(player[i])
print(player)
```

now `player == [[9], [9]]`

```
player[i].append(rc(cards))
print(player)
```

now `player == [[9, 10], [9, 10]]`

when I type `player[i].append(rc(cards))` I actualy want player to be

```
[[9, rc], [9]] #so in this example I would expect [[9, 10], [9]]
```

with `rc` being the random number from cards, but somehow I get

```
[[9, rc], [9, rc]] #so in this example i get [[9, 10], [9, 10]]
```

Does anyone know why and could someone please help me how I can just change the first element?

PS: This is my first question here, so if I did something wrong (related to the question), please let me know.

Comment: `player.append(list(player[i]))` or `player.append(player[i][:])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
player.append(player[i])
```

The two elements of `player` are both references to the same list. When you modify the list, it's reflected in both elements. You need to make a copy:

```
player.append(player[i][:])
```